# repeat event by days with occurrences

Tags: php

```
<?php
function getDateOfWeekDay($day) {
    $weekDays = array(
      'Sunday',
      'Monday',
      'Tuesday',
      'Wednesday',
      'Thursday',
      'Friday',
      'Saturday',
    );

    $dayNumber = array_search($day, $weekDays);
    $currentDayNumber =  date('w', strtotime('today'));

   // if ($dayNumber > $currentDayNumber) {
 if ( $currentDayNumber > $dayNumber) {
      //return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day));
       echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($day.' this week'));
    } else {
      //return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($day) + 604800);
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($day.' next week') +1);
    }
  }


 $ron="0,2,6"; // $ron is repeats on every sunday , tuesday, and saturday
 $oc=4; // $oc is an occurrences how many time it will repeat
 $ronS=explode(',', $ron);
 foreach($ronS as $ronS) {
   $res[]= $ronS;
 }
 $r=0; 
 $rr=0;
 for($i = 0; $i < $oc; $i++)
 {
      if($i<count($res))
                     {
                      $t=$res[$i];
                      $r++;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                      $t=$res[$rr];
                      $rr++;
                     }
                     $week = array('0'=>"Sunday","1"=>"Monday","2"=>"Tuesday","3"=>"Wednesday","4"=>"Thursday","5"=>"Friday","6"=>"Saturday");
                     $day[] = $week[$t];
 }//for
print_r($day);
 foreach ($day  as $da)
 {
   echo  getDateOfWeekDay($da)."\n";
 }
?>
```

the output of this code is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sunday
    [1] => Tuesday
    [2] => Saturday
    [3] => Sunday
)
2014-05-18
2014-05-20
2014-05-24
2014-05-18
```

All working fine but the last date **2014-05-18** is wrong it will be `2014-05-25`

Comment: Please add more explanation about what you are doing here and why that result is wrong.

Comment: `foreach($ronS as $ronS)` Seriously ? You are overwriting your array while foreaching it. Avoid this, and please give your variables better names than `ron`, `oc`, `r` and `rr`, because we can help you so much better when we understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: $ron="0,2,6";// here 0-sunday , 1- monday.....
 $oc=4; // $oc is an occurence how many time the event will repeat based on $ron input

Comment: http://codepad.org/a5LPB9A6

Comment: The problem Sunday is repeating.So you need to do some mechanism to get date from next week if the value is repeating

Comment: try like this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fcfc0ec58b2bbac3f17c96e9bbe26ca22c61d93

Comment: yes but pls increase the $oc=6 , again the looping problem friend